# Return value of virtual functions in interface

Tags: c++, interface, virtual, void, void-pointers

One class returns 'int', other returns 'double'. What is the signature of method 'GiveMeTheValue' in the interface of both classes. 
I want to compile following code:

```cpp
class Interface
{
    public:
        virtual arbitrary_type GimeMeTheValue(void) {}; 
};

class TakeInt : public Interface
{
    public:
        arbitrary_type GimeMeTheValue(void) {
            return 10;
        }
};

class TakeDouble : public Interface
{
    public:
        arbitrary_type GimeMeTheValue(void) { 
            return 3.14;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Interface * obj;

    obj = new TakeInt(); 
    cout << obj -> GimeMeTheValue() << endl; // It's 10, thank you

    obj = new TakeDouble();
    cout << obj -> GimeMeTheValue() << endl; // Oh it's 3.14, I love you c++
}
```

Of course there is no such an "arbitary_type".
This works ...

```cpp
class Interface
{
    public:
        virtual void * GimeMeTheValue(void) {}; 
};

class TakeInt : public Interface
{
    public:
        void * GimeMeTheValue(void) {
            int value = 10;
            int * ptr = &value;
            return ptr; 
        }
};

class TakeDouble : public Interface
{
    public:
        void * GimeMeTheValue(void) { 
            double value = 3.14;
            double * ptr = &value;
            return ptr; 
        }
};

int main()
{
    Interface * obj;

    obj = new TakeInt();
    cout << *( (int *) (obj -> GimeMeTheValue()) ) << endl;

    obj = new TakeDouble();
    cout << *( (double *) (obj -> GimeMeTheValue()) ) << endl;
}
```

It is rather complicated to deal with "void *". Are there any other ideas to implement something simple (like in the first code example)? Thank you.

Comment: You return pointers to local variables. Never do it :-).

Comment: `virtual void * GimeMeTheValue(void) {};` *doesn't* puke a compiler warning about not returning a value? This *appears* to be a decent candidate for a *variant* type. As written, this invokes undefined behavior in multiple locations

Comment: WhozCraig, yes, undefined behavior. But are there any alternatives? I need one (!) virtual function name for all my classes. But each class returns its own type of value. So what is the signature?!

Comment: @Pleeea again, it looks to be a decent candidate for a *variant* type; a type that is capable of representing multiple fundamental types, (but of course, only one at any given time).

Comment: In the case of this code, the `Interface` class is not actually a good candidate for a common interface - the derived classes do different things and return different results. Although they have similar signatures they are not the same. This is a candidate for a template base class rather than a concrete abstract base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way the base class `Interface` could know what distinct data type each descendant wants to return.  Using different return types defeats the purpose of polymorphism.  So the only way I can think to do this is to have `GiveMeTheValue()` return an object type that knows what kind of value it holds, and then make that object streamable.

```
enum VariantType {varNull, varInt, varDouble};

struct Variant
{
    VariantType Type;
    union {
        int intValue;
        double dblValue;
    };

    Variant() : Type(varNull) {}
    Variant(int value) : Type(varInt), intValue(value) {}
    Variant(double value) : Type(varDouble), dblValue(value) {}

    void writeTo(std::ostream &strm)
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case varNull:   strm << "(null)"; break;
            case varInt:    strm << intValue; break;
            case varDouble: strm << dblValue; break; 
        }
    }
};

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() {}
    virtual Variant GimeMeTheValue(void) = 0; 
};

class TakeInt : public Interface
{
public:
    Variant GimeMeTheValue(void)
    {
        return Variant(10);
    }
};

class TakeDouble : public Interface
{
public:
    Variant GimeMeTheValue(void)
    { 
        return Variant(3.14);
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const Variant &v)
{
    v.writeTo(strm);
    return strm;
}

int main()
{
    Interface * obj;

    obj = new TakeInt(); 
    cout << obj->GimeMeTheValue() << endl; // It's 10, thank you
    delete obj;

    obj = new TakeDouble();
    cout << obj->GimeMeTheValue() << endl; // Oh it's 3.14, I love you c++
    delete obj;
}
```

Comment: >> Using different return types defeats the purpose of polymorphism. << I think that's the main problem in my logic, thank you

Comment: @Pleeea: Yes. You want to use an object via a base class pointer without caring what the derived class actually is, only that all derived classes implement a consistent interface. That is the essence of polymorphism. A virtual function cannot have different return types. It can only return 1 distinct type that all derived classes must adhere to. So, to have derived classes return different types, you need a distinct return type that can adjust its behavior at runtime, that is what a variant does.